# jQuery setupSearchButton animate broken after 2 times clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search button on my website, i have a function that wil animate my input field when clicking by moving it to the right. And if i click out of it then it wil close.

This works only after like 2 times open/close it is broken and won't animate anymorge. I added a `console.log();`  so i can see what its doing.

[image: Screenshot from my console.]

Here is my function.

```
function setupSearchButton()
{
    j(".icon").click(function() {
        var icon = j(this),
        input = icon.parent().find("#search"),
        submit = icon.parent().find(".submit"),
        is_submit_clicked = false;
        j(".searchform").animate({ "margin-left": "+=180px", "display": "block !important" }, "slow", function(){
            console.log("Move the searchbar to the right 180px;");
        });

        // Animate the input field
        input.animate({
            "width": "165px",
            "opacity": 1
        }, 300, function() {
            input.focus();
        });

        submit.mousedown(function() {
            is_submit_clicked = true;
        });

        // Now, we need to hide the icon too
        icon.fadeOut(300);

        input.blur(function() {
            if(!input.val() && !is_submit_clicked) {
                input.animate({
                    "width": "0",
                    "padding": "0",
                    "opacity": 0
                }, 200);
                // Get the icon back
                icon.fadeIn(200);
                j(".searchform").animate({ "margin-left": "-=180px", "display": "block !important" }, "slow", function(){
                    console.log("Move the searchbar back by adding a negative -180px to the left.");
                });
            };
        });
    });
}
```

Also i'm using "noconflict".

So what i'm doing wrong here ?.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the field is animated. if it is animated then return otherwise apply animation. Try with below code sample inside click function.

```
input = icon.parent().find("#search");
if(input.is(":animated")){
  // return if Animate applied.
   return;
}
else
{
   // Animate the input field
   input.animate({
     "width": "165px",
     "opacity": 1
   }, 300, function() {
      input.focus();
   });
}
```